# Sorting of files with numerical names in Java

Tags: java, file, sorting

I need to sort the files by name in right order, like in default Windows Explorer.
The standard java String Comparator works well until there is only alphabetical value. If there are any numbers in name, it works wrong, e.g:
The file with name "15 - abc.txt" will be upper in list than "2 - abc.txt".
What is the best way to resolve this issue for multilanguage case (java.text.Collator should be used)?

Comment: So, in other words, you don't want it to work like in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Looks like you have your own answer: *`java.text.Collator` should be used*. Have you at least tried it?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement your own comparator that takes into consideration the numbers as you want. This comparator may split the file name by groups: digits separately from other characters.

For example `15-abc-32b.txt` will produce array `{"15", "abc", "32", "b"}`. Now comparison of such arrays is simple. You should go over the elements and try to parse them using `Integer.pareseInt()`. If parsing succeeds compare appropriate numbers, otherwise compare strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Comparator and implement compare() method by comparing integer and String fields of your file names separately in sequence.

Comment: Note that `java.text.Collator` already implements `Comparator` interface. From [its Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html): *The Collator class performs locale-sensitive String comparison. You use this class to build searching and sorting routines for natural language text.*

Answer (score 1):

Taking into consideration that NumberFormat parses "15-abc-32b.txt" as 15 (see API) you can sort files like this

```
    String[] files = new File("dir").list();
    Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<String>() {
        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        public int compare(String f1, String f2) {
            try {
                return Double.compare(f.parse(f1).longValue(), f.parse(f2).longValue());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(f1 + "|" + f2);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Bad way. If i have the file called "abc - (1).txt" that should not work.